# Clicking the Element in selenium in local browser where else in browser stack it shows "Stale element error"?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browserstack

Running Selenium Test. And While running all the test cases execute without any error while running from my eclipse ide in chrome browser.But while i run the script in browser stack elements are not clicked by selenium and it throws stale element error. What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: Can you share error it throws?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Stale Element Exception -
Stale element exception can be caused because of the following reason -

- The element is detached from the document object model (DOM)
- The element is deleted or removed
- Read about this exception [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)

You may review the logs to determine if there was a page change or DOM change that could have triggered the exception. Did you try contacting [the BrowserStack support team](https://www.browserstack.com/contact?ref=help)?

Answer (score 0):

Usually we get this Exception when the element get's updated or changed and you are trying to access it at the time. From your question I can see that it's working on your local machine, so just make sure the browser version and the third party driver's you use are up to date. Also check the driver files path(chromedriver.exe etc) is correctly pointed in the Browser stack